# Lambda Consume Data From SQS In Batch

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a use case where I need a lambda function to only be triggered to consume data from an SQS queue once there are at least N messages. One solution I saw on another post is to configure a CloudWatch alarm that monitors the size of the queue. When the size of the queue >= N, the alarm will get triggered which will trigger the lambda function.

Instead of using this approach though, I'm wondering if there's a way I can use the built in Batch Window and Batch Size features when configuring a Lambda SQS trigger. The issue with using these features is that even if the batch size is less than N, every 5 minutes my lambda will still get triggered since the max batch window size is 5 minutes. I'm wondering if it's possible to do a no-op in these cases. So if my lambda gets triggered after 5 minutes, I check the batch size in my lambda code and then return the data back to the queue if it's not large enough for processing.

Comment: It's never a good idea to design an architecture that "sends messages back to a queue". This would either involve failing the messages (which then triggers error-handling logic) or sending them as 'new messages', which can just make things worse. Can you tell us more about your use-case? For example, why do you need at least _N_ messages? Are the messages related to each other? For example, are you waiting for somebody to upload _N_ files and then you want to process them together? If we know more about your use-case, we might be able to offer an alternative.

Comment: Thanks John. The reason I need at least N messages is because I am invoking some downstream systems which are inefficient to invoke on small batches. The messages will be coming without any pattern, and I want to avoid triggering my downstream workflows without having enough messages to justify it

Comment: Sounds like you'll need some way to buffer the messages until enough arrive. The CloudWatch alarm on queue size sounds good, but might have problems with how often it runs and how quickly the messages become 'invisible'. For example, if there are lots of messages, it might take several minutes before invoking the Lambda function enough to clear the queue. It's worth experimenting, since the Batch Window doesn't look like it will work as you stated.

Comment: I am thinking about using an AWS Glue job that runs periodically to help batch the data. So I will have a lambda that reads data from SQS and writes the data to S3. then I will have an AWS Glue job that runs every few hours to batch data and output it in a new S3 location for further processing. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: If you just want to trigger it "every few hours", then you could simply do it with a scheduled Lambda function. Instead of having SQS trigger Lambda, trigger it via schedule. Then the Lambda function could directly call SQS and 'suck out' all the messages (might require repeated calls to `ReceiveMessages()`. Then, do the bulk processing of the data.